# Why NSFetchRequest always fetched the recently create entity even the entity is out of fetch offset?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a data model with just one record, a NSFetchResult instance that was set up with fetchOffset at 10.

```
Assets: NSManagedObject
```

```
let fetchRequest = Assets.fetchRequest()
```

After saving a new data model I run the request I got 2 entities from the fetch result.

```
let fetchResult = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Assets]
```

I scheduled a dispatch queue to run exactly the same fetch request after 10s then the result is empty as I expected.

```
let fetchResult = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Assets]
```

Can you give me any advice?

How can I should do to make the fetch result work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have unsaved changes in your context in the first call. Try setting:

```
fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
```

Comment: You are right, I have checked the code.
There was missed the save block